Communicate current output stream before terminating subprocess
On Windows, I am terminating Popen subprocess if it runs too long.
Is there any way to collect output and error stream before kill is invoked?
I create a sample child process which prints number 0 to 5 and takes 5 second.
child.py
import time

i = 1
while True:
    print(i)
    if i == 5:
        break
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

Then I create a parent which terminates child after 2 seconds.
parent.py
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["C:\\..\\python.exe", "C:\\child.py"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
time.sleep(2)
p.kill()
output, error = p.communicate()
print(output)

My expectation would be that p.communicate() returns what child has managed to write into output within 2 seconds, i.e. something like b'0\r\n1\r\n. However, the output is empty.
When I reverse the order of methods, then parent waits for child to finish which is not desired.
time.sleep(2)
output, error = p.communicate()  # takes 3 seconds
print(output)  # returns b'0\r\n1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n'
p.kill()


If the process was buffering output, killing the process prevents it from flushing the buffer. So the output is irretrievably lost.

Is it possible to flush only what is currently available?

Flushing must be done by the producer, not the consumer.

Can you change child.py? Modify it to disable buffering.

No control over child.py. Strange we can flush the buffer when process finishes properly but not interim.

We don't flush the buffer, the process flushes its own buffer. It's part of the normal exit code.

What about writing output into a file? Would it then be possible to access what has been written thus far?

Writing to files is usually buffered.

On Linux, you can run a program through unbuffer to redirect its output to a pty, so it will be line-buffered by default. I don't know if there's anything equivalent on Windows.

Thanks @Barmar. This was helpful. I shall probably delete the question or leave as is.
